# how to access files on a different partition on a different physical drive from konsole

Tags: partitioning, 22.04, cd

I have Ubuntu 22.04 and a computer with 2 physical drives. Each drive has a single primary partition. If I start the computer and open a terminal, it opens to the boot partition, so it would looks something like:

```
bob@mycomputer:~$
```

Is there a way I can use cd to switch to a folder on the other partition on the other physical drive? I was trying to find some information about this, and I read something about possibly having to mount the other partition in /etc/fstab and treat it as a mounted partition? Is that how you do it, or is there some way to directly change to the other partition?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that it was automatically mounting it, but it was in:

```
/media/bob/mypartition
```

and not in

```
/mnt
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way to find out mountpoints is to run the `mounts` command or inspect into `/proc/mounts`, not listing directories.

##### Example of the command `mounts`

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ mount
/dev/sda2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sda4 on /tmp type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/sda6 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sda5 on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime)
```

##### Example of `/proc/mounts`

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ cat /proc/mounts
/dev/sda2 / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/sda4 /tmp ext4 rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/sda6 /boot/efi vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/sda5 /home ext4 rw,relatime 0 0
```

`/proc/mounts` is more machine-readable, and `mounts` is more human-readable.